# How do I change the interpolation of multiple keyframes in the graph editor (f-curve)?

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor, interpolation

When I select multiple keyframes in the f-curve view (graph editor) and change the interpolation to "constant", it only changes one keyframe, so how do I change it for multiple keyframes?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

While can't see how you do it, here is how i do it:

1. You frame all the wanted keyframes including their handles
2. Either go in the menu on top or use the context menu with <kbd>RMB</kbd> to change the
   interpolation.

Here also a visual step by step:

[image]

Should this not work with your version, please explain where it differs from this.